# Posting Array data in Ajax in JavaScript and Reading the parameter at server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am posting array data in json format to Google app script server.My concern is how to read the data at serverside

```
                var url = myappscripturl;
                var mydata = { 
                    name : "sunil",
                    arraydata :  [
                        {
                            phone:'7898',
                            landline : '2678-789'
                        },
                        {
                            phone:'87658',
                            landline : '0672348'
                        }

                    ] 
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url : url,
                    method:'POST',
                    data:mydata,
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                })
```

//Google App Script doPost method:

```
function doPost(e){
try{
var result = {"result7":e.parameter};
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(result);
return ContentService.createTextOutput(jsondata).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
catch(e){
var error = {"error":e};
  var jsonerror = JSON.stringify(error);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(jsonerror).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

}
}
```

Getting Response in the Console:

```
result7:
arraydata[0][landline]: "2678-789"
arraydata[0][phone]: "7898"
arraydata[1][landline]: "0672348"
arraydata[1][phone]: "87658"
name: "sunil"
```

**How do i read the phone numbers at server side ?**
Tried to use the JSON.parse(e.parameter) at serverside but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Notes:

- `jquery`'s POST method, by default posts content as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`and not as `application/json`.
- `POST` is sent as:

  ```
  arraydata[0][phone]=7898&
  arraydata[0][landline]=2678-789&
  name=sunil&
  arraydata[1][landline]=0672348&
  arraydata[1][phone]=87658
  ```
- Note that `arraydata` is converted as plain string keys.
- You can access the `phone` as

  ```
  const phone = e.parameter["arraydata[1][phone]"];//87658
  const phones = e.parameters["arraydata[1][phone]"];//[87658]
  ```

#### References:

- [jQuery#ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [jQuery#param](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)
- [Apps script#Web app guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)